# GoF design pattern detection

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a Java project. I want to identify GoF design patterns in the application.

I tried to use "Design Pattern detection using Similarity Scoring" Java applet but I do not think it's sufficient enough. Still, I tried to used Reclipse as well but really dont know how to use it properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There are thousand of occourences in the JDK itself. A Java Applet is a totaly different thing. Reclipse is reverse engineering - how do you think it has something to do with GOF-patterns?

Comment: Thank Peter Rader. I am sorry for my limited knowledge. "Reclipse is a reverse engineering tool for the automatic detection of patterns in source code". I guess it's different with GoF pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read through the book and learn about the design patterns there, then look through the code to see what patterns look similar. In this way, you might learn something useful about design patterns instead of just putting and answer down on your assignment.

Comment: Thank you The Thom. Actually I read the book but it seems to be overwhelming to detect multiple patterns there because I am new to it. I am trying to do it manually by drawing relationship between classes. I am not sure it's the good way. Do you think it's a good way to do it?

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure that drawing relationships are your shortest path. Most patterns are behavioural. I would start by walking through each part of the code and saying, "What is this chunk of code accomplishing?" Then, go through the descriptions in the front of the book that describe each pattern and see if that pattern has that behaviour.

Comment: The rest are construction patterns. It shouldn't take long to find each place where an object is constructed and there are only a handful of construction patterns in the front of the book. This part should go quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much The Thom. I have following your advice for 2 hours and can say it is great.